# Parse.com PFQueryTableViewController cell imageView placeholder image

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, parse-platform, xcode6

I have a Swift app in which I have a `PFQueryTableViewController`, and I am trying to use a placeholder image in my cells. Here is the code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {

    let cellIdentifier = "GroupCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as PFTableViewCell

    let uIImage = UIImage(named: "ios7-people 40x40")
    cell.imageView.image = uIImage

    return cell
}
```

This produces an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

at cell.imageView.image assignment line. I have tested the same UIImage in other part of my app, and its working as expected. A small fragment of the debug console for the imageView is shown here: https://copy.com/SATs4axVmrg9Rhay

What am I doing wrong here? I just want to put a placeholder image for all the cells. I haven't explicitly added an UIImageView to the cell in my storyboard BTW.

Comment: `cell`'s probably nil.

Comment: Have you registered the cell class elsewhere in your code using `registerClass(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)`?

Comment: @LyndseyScott What do you mean registering the cell class elsewhere? My apologies I'm new to iOS dev, Swift, and Xcode. I'm following the directions given here: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-tables/iOS and https://gist.github.com/jamesyu/ba03c1a550f14f88f95d Can you please elaborate?